# Solution of the nonlinear ODE $y'' y' =A y' y + B (x-1) y$, with $y(0) = 1$, $y(1) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What analytical techniques are available for finding solutions to the nonlinear ODE
$$y'' y' =A y' y + B (x-1) y,$$ with boundary conditions $$y(0) = 1, \quad y(1) = 0,$$
where $A$ and $B$ are positive, real constants? Unfortunately, neither $A$ nor $B$ are necessarily small.

Does assuming that $y'(x) \neq 0$ allow further progress?

Comment: Note that $$y(x)=0$$ is one solution.

Comment: $y(x) = 0$ does not satisfy the boundary condition $y(0) = 1$

Comment: Did you try the Bellman-Kalaba Quasi-linearization method?

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I haven't tried this yet. Is https://www.rand.org/pubs/reports/R438.html the standard reference for the technique? I cannot access this paper through my university without paying for a copy.

Comment: i can send you a copy if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $t=x-1$ ,

Then $y'y''=Ayy'+Bty$ with $y(-1)=1$ and $y(0)=0$

$y''=Ay+\dfrac{Bty}{y'}$ with $y(-1)=1$ and $y(0)=0$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}=Ay+\dfrac{Bty}{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}$ with $y(-1)=1$ and $y(0)=0$

$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)=Ay+\dfrac{Bty}{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}$ with $y(-1)=1$ and $y(0)=0$

$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{dt}{dy}}\right)=Ay+Bty\dfrac{dt}{dy}$ with $t(1)=-1$ and $t(0)=0$

$\dfrac{d}{dy}\left(\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{dt}{dy}}\right)\dfrac{dy}{dt}=Ay+Bty\dfrac{dt}{dy}$ with $t(1)=-1$ and $t(0)=0$

$-\dfrac{\dfrac{d^2t}{dy^2}}{\left(\dfrac{dt}{dy}\right)^3}=Ay+Bty\dfrac{dt}{dy}$ with $t(1)=-1$ and $t(0)=0$

$\dfrac{d^2t}{dy^2}=-Ay\left(\dfrac{dt}{dy}\right)^3-Bty\left(\dfrac{dt}{dy}\right)^4$ with $t(1)=-1$ and $t(0)=0$

You can consider as the ODE of the type http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=429

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a further hint? This substitution for $x$ doesn't seem to have much effect on the form of the equation. I've been looking for substitutions for $y$ without much luck so far

Comment: It would be great to have some more details. I found the book you linked to, although somewhere else because the link seems broken, and unfortunately the section (2.6, and specifically 2.6.4) that discusses equations of the relevant form doesn't appear to cover the actual combination of terms in the question - unless I missed it! Do you know if it's covered in the book? Thanks